# Unable to bind json data (api result) to dropdown using jquery/js in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind json data returned by API to dropdownlist.
but unable to fetch value id and name.
Json Format :

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "categories": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "CatOne"
            }
        },
        {
            "categories": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "CatTwo"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am returning JsonResult, using

```
return Json(responseData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and in Jquery call ,I am using

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/City",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    global: false,
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jsonObj) {
        var listItems = "";
        //here I want to get id and name
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your json should be `[{ id: 1, name: "CatOne" }, { id: 2, name: "CatTwo" }]` and then you can use a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate dropdown from your `json` like following.

```js
var json = {
        "categories": [
            { "categories": { "id": 1, "name": "CatOne" } },
            { "categories": { "id": 2, "name": "CatTwo" } }
        ]
    }

$.each(json.categories, function () {
    $('select').append('<option value="' + this.categories.id + '">' + this.categories.name + '</option>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just stick a break point (or `debugger;` statement) inside your success callback. Then you can inspect your `jsonObj` and it'll tell you exactly what you need to know.

In this case, you should be able to iterate on `jsonObj.categories`, and your id and name properties will be accessible via `jsonObject.categories[i].categories.id` and `jsonObject.categories[i].categories.name`

So your success method will look something like:

`for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.categories.length; i++) {
  var category = jsonObj.categories[i].categories;
  var id = category.id;
  var name = category.name;
}`

I would also suggest formatting your json differently, as other answers have suggested.